# Destruction of non-pointer members of a class

Tags: c++

When is a non-pointer member of a class destructed? Example:

```
class foo {
   private:
    int a;
   public:
    foo(int sa):a(sa){}
    ~foo(){}//does anything need to be done here?
 };

{
   foo(10);
}//the destructor is called
```

Should anything be done inside the destructor? Thanks!

Comment: just for the note, members in the class are private by default if they are declared before any access label. So that `class foo { int a; };` will have `a` as a private member.

Comment: Thanks. Usually I put the private: there just to remind myself ;-)

Comment: "When is a non-pointer member of a class destructed?" - do I get any pedantry points if I say that all the answers so far refer only to *non-static* members? Assuming normal program exit, static members are destroyed in reverse order of their construction, and intermingled with `atexit` handlers, each handler being run in the reverse sequence at the point corresponding to when it was registered. If `abort` is called, then static members are not destroyed. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not a thing. `a` will be destroyed after any code in your destructor completes. In a case like this, you don't even need to declare a destructor; the compiler will do the right thing on its own.

Comment: Compiler will just do nothing as pod types don't have to be destroyed :-D

Comment: @Vlad: Correct. But if `a` were of class type, it would also be properly destroyed.

Comment: This is surreal. a isn't of class type, Vlad!

Answer (score 1):

An object's contents are destroyed in inverse order of their appearance in the class definition after the execution of the object's destructor.

Answer (score 0):

A non-pointer member of an object is destructed after the containing object's destructor has completed.

Comment: Technically, this applies to pointer members too--it's just that the (theoretical) destructor of a pointer does nothing. :)

Comment: @Jonathan: Right. I *almost* mentioned that but figured that the distinction wasn't important in the context of the OP's question. :-)

Comment: I think that you mean that you thought the distinction *was* important because you made it... *created* it even.  There's actually no difference between a pointer and any other raw-type member in the context of the OP's question.

Comment: @Noah: In practical terms there's a distinction between POD types and other types, and a pointer is POD. I think that's what @Laurence was getting at.

Comment: @Noah: I didn't create the distinction. The OP did. He asked "When is a non-pointer member of a class destructed?".